# Python 'pip install' not working/recognised

Tags: python, pip, python-3.10

I've been trying to use the "pip install" python command for a while but have had no luck.

I have checked that pip came in the python installer package, tried repairing the program on the installer and have even tried installing the Python 3.10 app from the Microsoft store (instead of using IDLE) and running the command from there. Nothing has worked at the moment.

This is what I get (IDLE Python 3.10 in the main idle shell terminal):

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Where are you running this command? `pip` is a command line program. What happens when you run `pip` in a command line?

Comment: Yes I was writing the commands on the main terminal (IDLE shell).

Comment: `SyntaxError` is likely the python interpreter telling you that what you pasted into the terminal is not valid py code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running pip inside of Python. That's not how it should be used. Open a terminal and try

```
python -m pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

or

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

Comment: Yes I was running the command in the terminal but it does not work for both commands.

Comment: @aPythonUser You were running the command in a **Python** terminal. Open command prompt, or the bash terminal, etc... The error you recieved is specifically a Python error, you would not see it unless you wrote the command in Python. If you are truly in a terminal, you've managed to get yourself into python (probably by writing `python`). Type `quit()` and try again.